# Fill WinForms Control to Parent

Tags: winforms, f#, .net-7.0

I am attempting to build a simple text editor in F# with WinForms. I would like to know how to get items to fill their parent containers most easily, and I am finding that a text box is not filling its parent despite its `Dock` property being set to `DockStyle.Fill`. I would like both the top `MenuStrip` and the `RichTextBox` to fill the parent containers and take up the whole form (as you'd expect to see in a text editor). Here is a screenshot demonstrating the issue:

[image: Text Edit area too small!]

As you can see, it would be nice to have both the MenuStrip and RichTextBox to fill the entire form.

Here is the code (along with the `.fsproj` file):

Program.fs:

```
module FsEdit.Program

open System
open System.Windows.Forms

[<EntryPoint; STAThread>]
let main argv =
    Application.Run FsEdit.MainForm.MainForm
    0
```

MainForm.fs:

```
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module FsEdit.MainForm

open System.Windows.Forms

// MenuBar
let private FileMenuTab =
    new ToolStripMenuItem(
        Text = "File"
    )

let private EditMenuTab =
    new ToolStripMenuItem(
        Text = "Edit"
    )

let private AboutMenuTab =
    new ToolStripMenuItem(
        Text = "About"
    )

let private MainMenuStrip =
    new MenuStrip(
        Text = "MainMenuStrip"
    )

let private allMenuStripItems =
    [|
        FileMenuTab
        EditMenuTab
        AboutMenuTab
    |]
    |> Array.map (fun tab -> tab :> ToolStripItem)
    
MainMenuStrip.Items.AddRange(allMenuStripItems)

// Text Editor
let private MainTextBox =
    let richTextBox = new RichTextBox(
        Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut a eleifend nunc. Suspendisse non purus varius, ullamcorper arcu et, vehicula lacus. Integer pellentesque facilisis interdum. Aliquam id leo arcu. Nam mauris nisl, semper eget massa sed, aliquam convallis lacus. Etiam a neque blandit, sollicitudin nisl quis, ornare dui. Aliquam nec lorem sit amet arcu iaculis elementum rutrum eu velit. Curabitur dignissim blandit ligula at efficitur. Curabitur id justo quis tortor egestas ultrices. Nam arcu quam, ullamcorper id velit quis, aliquam finibus libero. Pellentesque semper fermentum sem a scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;"
    )
    richTextBox.Dock <- DockStyle.Fill
    richTextBox.Anchor <- AnchorStyles.Left ||| AnchorStyles.Right ||| AnchorStyles.Top
    richTextBox.AllowDrop <- true
    richTextBox.AutoSize <- true
    richTextBox

let private MainTextBoxPanel =
    let p = new FlowLayoutPanel()
    p.Dock <- DockStyle.Fill
    p.WrapContents <- false
    p.FlowDirection <- FlowDirection.TopDown
    p.Anchor <- AnchorStyles.Left ||| AnchorStyles.Right ||| AnchorStyles.Top
    p

MainTextBoxPanel.Controls.Add(MainMenuStrip)
MainTextBoxPanel.Controls.Add(MainTextBox)

// MainForm
let MainForm =
    let form = new Form(
        Text = "FsEdit"
    )
    form.Width <- 800
    form.Height <- 600
    form
    
MainForm.Controls.Add(MainTextBoxPanel)
```

FsEdit.fsproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
        <UseWpf>true</UseWpf>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="MainForm.fs" />
        <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

How do I get these Control objects to fill their respective parents successfully?

Comment: Use a Panel instead of FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: @RezaAghaei no better: https://imgur.com/Hk3pnKl

Comment: Also, don't add the MenuStrip and the RichTextBox to the same Panel. You can dock the MenuStrip to Top (on the Form) and the Panel that contains the RTB to Fill -- Note that you cannot both Dock and Anchor your Controls Pick one or the other -- You could also use a TableLayoutPanel (which allows docking child Controls, not the FLP - directly) as container for both the MenuStrip and the Container of the RichTextBox and dock the TLP to Fill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is expected for a FlowLayoutPanel having TopDown flow direction. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-and-dock-child-controls-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control?source=recommendations&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235):

> This is the general rule for anchoring and docking in the FlowLayoutPanel control: for vertical flow directions, the FlowLayoutPanel control calculates the width of an implied column from the widest child control in the column. All other controls in this column with Anchor or Dock properties are aligned or stretched to fit this implied column.

If you'd like to dock the controls to top and fill, you don't need a FlowLayoutPanel. Use a Panel instead.

You can use either of the following layouts:

```
- Form
    - Menu (Dock = Top)
    - RichTextBox (Dock = Fill)
```

Or if for ant reason you want to host both the menu and the text editor in the same panel as container:

```
- Form
    - Panel (Dock = Fill)
        - Menu (Dock = Top)
        - RichTextBox (Dock = Fill)
```

***Important Note:*** Pay attention to the order that you add controls to the form. Z-order of the controls is important and has impact on the result. Controls are docked in reverse z-order. You may want to learn more about [how to dock and anchor controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-dock-and-anchor?view=netdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) in Windows Forms.

**To learn more:**

- [How to: Anchor and Dock Child Controls in a FlowLayoutPanel Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-and-dock-child-controls-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control?source=recommendations&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [FlowLayoutPanel control overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/flowlayoutpanel-control-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Position and layout of controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/layout?view=netdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How to dock and anchor controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-dock-and-anchor?view=netdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

**Example 1 - Docking Menu to Top, RichTextBox to Fill, and StatusStrip to Bottom**

Use the following code for the form, it will dock Menu to Top, RichTextBox to Fill, and StatusStrip to Bottom, without using any other container:

```
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module FsEdit.MainForm

open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing

// Main menu strip
let private FileMenuTab =
    new ToolStripMenuItem(
        Text = "File"
    )

let private EditMenuTab =
    new ToolStripMenuItem(
        Text = "Edit"
    )

let private AboutMenuTab =
    new ToolStripMenuItem(
        Text = "About"
    )

let private MainMenuStrip =
    let m = new MenuStrip(
        Text = "MainMenuStrip"
    )
    m

let private allMenuStripItems =
    [|
        FileMenuTab
        EditMenuTab
        AboutMenuTab
    |]
    |> Array.map (fun tab -> tab :> ToolStripItem)
    
MainMenuStrip.Items.AddRange(allMenuStripItems)

// Text Editor
let private MainTextBox =
    let richTextBox = new RichTextBox(
        Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut a eleifend nunc. Suspendisse non purus varius, ullamcorper arcu et, vehicula lacus. Integer pellentesque facilisis interdum. Aliquam id leo arcu. Nam mauris nisl, semper eget massa sed, aliquam convallis lacus. Etiam a neque blandit, sollicitudin nisl quis, ornare dui. Aliquam nec lorem sit amet arcu iaculis elementum rutrum eu velit. Curabitur dignissim blandit ligula at efficitur. Curabitur id justo quis tortor egestas ultrices. Nam arcu quam, ullamcorper id velit quis, aliquam finibus libero. Pellentesque semper fermentum sem a scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;"
    )
    richTextBox.Dock <- DockStyle.Fill
    richTextBox.AllowDrop <- true
    richTextBox.AutoSize <- true
    richTextBox

let private MainStatusBar =
    let s = new StatusStrip()
    s.Dock <- DockStyle.Bottom 
    s

// MainForm
let MainForm =
    let form = new Form(
        Text = "FsEdit"
    )
    form.Width <- 800
    form.Height <- 600
    form.MinimumSize <- Size(320, 240)
    form
    
MainForm.Controls.Add(MainTextBox)
MainForm.Controls.Add(MainMenuStrip)
MainForm.Controls.Add(MainStatusBar)
```

[image]

Comment: The order of adding controls is also important, and have impact on the result of docking.

Comment: I think these answers are all good and provide a good starting point for basic GUI development in F# with WinForms. I'll accept this answer and hopefully in the future this will help other people get started with GUI development in pure F#, as is something I think is sorely lacking in the F# development world. Thanks!

Comment: I would also add emphasis on the "order of adding controls", and this is something that devs need to experiment with when they are adding controls to forms or other controls as the behavior can be a little unintuitive.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, added a section to the answer to highlight the importance of z-order.

Comment: This post directly answers your question, and I agree, it makes more sense to mark this one as accepted. I shared the other answer (not as a direct solution to your problem) but as a general solution for projects which many Forms and UI designs; in such cases using designer of WinForms will help a lot, as you will use the GUI designer and you see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

An option to make life easier for one who wants WinForms UI with F# is creating the UI with a Windows Forms Designer and using design UI with drag and drop and all the design-time features, then adding the reference the WinForms project to the F# project and add F# code. Follow the steps to see how it works in action:

[image]

**Example - WinForms UI Designer + F# Code**

1. **Create UI Project:** Create a WinForms Class Library (.NET 6) and set its name to `WinFormsFS.UI`

   You can create a WinForms Project or a WinForms Control Library as well and modify the project and files. The only thing that matters here, is the project output type which we'd like it to be class library, and we don't need main entry point in this project.

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
     <PropertyGroup>
       <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
       <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
       <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
       <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
     </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
   ```

   If you created a WinForms project, remove the Program.cs, or Form1. For WinForms Class Library, remove Class1, and for WinForms Control Library remove UserControl1. We don't need them for this examample.
2. **Add Form:** Add a new Form, and set its name `MainFormUI`
3. **Add controls:** Drop a MenuStrip, StatusStrip and a RichTextBox, and let them use their default names. The MenuStrip will be docked to top automatically, and the StatuStrip will be docked to bottom. You can setup all properties, or add menu items to the menu strip.
4. **Configure properties:** Dock the RichTextBox to Fill (using property editor, and setting Dock property, or using the smart tags panel  and choosing Dock in parent container.)
5. **Change access modifiers:** For the controls which you want to use in F# code, you need to change access modifier to public. To do so, Choose RichTextBox and in property browser, set its Modifiers to Public.
6. **Create the F# project:** Create a F# console app with name WinFormsFS.Code. And set is as startup project. Change the output type to win exe and use winfows forms. The project file should be like this:

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
     <PropertyGroup>
       <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
       <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
       <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
       <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <ItemGroup>
       <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
     </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
7. **Add WinForms project reference:** Right click on F# project and add reference to WinForms project.
8. **Add code for the UI:** Add a file `MainForm.fs` with the following code:

   ```
   namespace WinFormsFS.Code
   open System.Windows.Forms
   open WinFormsFS.UI

   type MainForm() as this = 
       inherit MainFormUI()
       do
           this.richTextBox1.Text <- "Lorem ipsum!"
   ```
9. **Add code for Startup:** Modify the Program.fs to the following:

   ```
   module WinFormsFS.Code.Program

   open System
   open System.Windows.Forms

   [<EntryPoint; STAThread>]
   let main args =
       Application.EnableVisualStyles()
       Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)
       Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware) |>ignore   
       Application.Run (new WinFormsFS.Code.MainForm())
       0
   ```

Run the program by pressing f5 and see the output. (Make sure the startup project is the F# project)

[image]

Comment: Much easier approach for a complex UI (using designer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried both the regular `Panel` approach per @Reza Aghaei and the `TableLayoutPanel` approach per @Jimi and decided to go with the latter as I was still getting overlap with the plain `Panel` objects. I also added a `StatusStrip` to the bottom of the Form, but found that if I added it to the `TableLayoutPanel` it would not display correctly even with the `Dock` set to `DocStyle.Bottom` ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYHzK.jpg)). (I will of course update if I find better programmatic solutions in F# for WinForms development.)

Here's a screenshot followed by the updated code:

[image]

MainWindow.fs:

```
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module FsEdit.MainForm

open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing

// Main panel
let private MainTableLayoutPanel =
    let t = new TableLayoutPanel()
    t.Dock <- DockStyle.Fill
    t
    
// Main menu strip
let private FileMenuTab =
    new ToolStripMenuItem(
        Text = "File"
    )

let private EditMenuTab =
    new ToolStripMenuItem(
        Text = "Edit"
    )

let private AboutMenuTab =
    new ToolStripMenuItem(
        Text = "About"
    )

let private MainMenuStrip =
    let m = new MenuStrip(
        Text = "MainMenuStrip"
    )
    m

let private allMenuStripItems =
    [|
        FileMenuTab
        EditMenuTab
        AboutMenuTab
    |]
    |> Array.map (fun tab -> tab :> ToolStripItem)
    
MainMenuStrip.Items.AddRange(allMenuStripItems)

// Text Editor
let private MainTextBox =
    let richTextBox = new RichTextBox(
        Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut a eleifend nunc. Suspendisse non purus varius, ullamcorper arcu et, vehicula lacus. Integer pellentesque facilisis interdum. Aliquam id leo arcu. Nam mauris nisl, semper eget massa sed, aliquam convallis lacus. Etiam a neque blandit, sollicitudin nisl quis, ornare dui. Aliquam nec lorem sit amet arcu iaculis elementum rutrum eu velit. Curabitur dignissim blandit ligula at efficitur. Curabitur id justo quis tortor egestas ultrices. Nam arcu quam, ullamcorper id velit quis, aliquam finibus libero. Pellentesque semper fermentum sem a scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;"
    )
    richTextBox.Dock <- DockStyle.Fill
    // richTextBox.Anchor <- AnchorStyles.Left ||| AnchorStyles.Right ||| AnchorStyles.Top ||| AnchorStyles.Bottom
    richTextBox.AllowDrop <- true
    richTextBox.AutoSize <- true
    richTextBox

let private MainStatusBar =
    let s = new StatusStrip()
    s.Dock <- DockStyle.Bottom // if anything other than "bottom" does not show up
    s

// Add controls to main panel
MainTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(MainMenuStrip)
MainTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(MainTextBox)

// MainForm
let MainForm =
    let form = new Form(
        Text = "FsEdit"
    )
    form.Width <- 800
    form.Height <- 600
    form.MinimumSize <- Size(320, 240)
    form
    
MainForm.Controls.Add(MainTableLayoutPanel)
MainForm.Controls.Add(MainStatusBar) // Adding to MainTableLayoutPanel makes it size incorrectly even with DockStyle.Bottom
```

Comment: TableLayoutPanel works, but it's quite unnecessary in this scenario.

Comment: I updated the answer with a sample code, docking properly without using an extra container. Look at the screenshot to see the result. Also pay attention to the order that I added controls.  Z-order of the controls is important and has impact on the result. Controls are docked in reverse z-order. If you want to learn more, take a look at the links in my answer, especially [this on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-dock-and-anchor?view=netdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).